# How can radiation negatively ionize an atom?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, ions

Ionizing radiation, as I've learnt it, ionizes an atom by supplying enough energy to essentially "knock" an electron off the atom  — that is, by *exciting* the electron to a level that is gets freed from the atom it was previously bound to. However, I had this belief contested by a Youtube video, whose host said that:

> [...] (the argon) atom can be made negatively charged by **having an electron put on it** [...]

How does that work? How can radiation negatively ionize an atom, not through the removal of a proton (like is discussed in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/598424/can-ionizing-radiation-cause-a-proton-to-be-removed-from-an-atom) thread) but rather by the addition of an extra electron (or more)?

---

**The entire context here is about ionizing radiation and how it could ionize an atom (in this case, Argon) negatively so an answer explaining that would be perfect.**

Comment: The knocked-off electron should go somewhere. That somewhere is the other atom that'll get negatively charged.

Comment: Is the YouTube video you mentioned specifically talking about ionizing radiation?  Or just ionization in general?  A link would be helpful.

Comment: It's talking about ionizing radiation in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusion here between *ionizing radiation* and *ionization/ions* in general.

**Ions** are atoms that lack electrosn or have some extra ones, which makes them positively/negatively charged.

**Ionizing radiation** kicks an electron (or more) from an atom, producing a positively charged ion.

**Ionization** can be achieved by different means, not necessarily via radiation. E.g., a $NaCl$ salt dissolved in water will separate into ions:
$$
NaCl \leftrightarrow Na^{+}+Cl^{-}
$$

In a gas ions can arise from atoms capturing electrons, e.g., if these electrons were previously released by other atoms as a result of ionizing radiation. In gas discharge tubes the ions may also arise from the electron flow, atomic collisions, or molecules torn apart by electric field.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert a typo, thanks.