# What is the wavelength range of X-rays?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, terminology, conventions, wavelength, x-rays

I was reading and came across the following paragraph

> The X-rays thus produced by many electrons make up the continuous spectrum of Figure 2-10 and are very many discrete photons whose wavelengths vary from $\lambda_{min}$ to infinity.

So, I am wondering how can it range to Infinity, I mean isn't the range of wavelengths that we call X-rays from 0.01nm to 10 nm?

Comment: Just read it charitably: the photons produced are from X-rays down to radio waves.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/561192/123208

Comment: TLDR: Sometimes, when you see "X-ray," the author is specifying a range of photon energies. Sometimes, the author is talking about photons produced by a specific process. The process (bombarding a metallic target with high-energy electrons) can produce photons with energies that are far outside of the band of energies that is traditionally called "X-ray."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Breaking up the electromagnetic spectrum into discrete bins (*x-rays, microwaves, radio waves,  ...*) is a tool which makes thinking about electromagnetic radiation easier. Putting hard limits on what you call an x-ray (e.g. $\lambda = 9$ nm is an x-ray, but $\lambda = 11$ nm isn't) is a pointless exercise - you should think about the categories more loosely than that.

In this passage, the author means that the process (Bremsstrahlung?) in question emits electromagnetic radiation which is primarily in the x-ray range, but in principle consists of all wavelengths above some $\lambda_{min}$. I think their passage gets the point across.